# Can't manipulate table row as parentNode of current cell with dom/xpath

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have a PHP-code like this

```
$html = '<div class="some_class"><table><tr><td>Tr0Td0</td><td>Tr0Td1</td></tr><tr><td>Tr1Td0</td><td>Tr1Td1</td></tr></table></div>';
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$div = $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class, "some_class")]')[0];
$table = $div->getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {
    if($td->nodeValue == 'Tr0Td1') {
        $td->parenNode->nextSibling->setAttribute('class','nextTR');
    }
}

echo $dom->saveXML($table);
```

In the `foreach()` loop I need to get the table row which is the next with regard to the row the current cell is in. But I can't do it, even get the row of the current cell. I get the 500 error in both cases.

What's wrong?

Comment: You have `parenNode`, should be `parentNode`.

Comment: is this a typo? `parenNode`, should have turned on error reporting or check the error logs